# Difference between host "@" and "origin" in DNS settings

Tags: dns

I was wondering if someone can give me an explanation of what "@" and "origin" means when pointing a domain to a certain IP.

Answer (score 0):

'@' means the root of a dns zone. It's is defined by RFC.
'$ORIGIN' indicate the default domain, which create by programmer.

So, when pointing a domain to a certain IP, '@' means the domain name it self (e.g. `example.com`).
While  'origin' means subdomain `origin.example.com`.